# Create terraform rules from list

Tags: openstack, terraform

I am using Terraform v0.11.11.
I want to be able to write a deployment script for openstack that takes a list of ip or ip range or arbitrary length that I want to white list in a vm for port 22, let say

`ip_list = ["11.11.0.0/16","22.22.22.0/8", "33.33.33.33" ...]`

It there a syntax to have the rule applying properly?

This is not working,

```
"openstack_compute_secgroup_v2" "secgroup_1" {
  name        = "a_cluster"
  description = "some security group"

  rule {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    ip_protocol = "tcp"
    cidr        = "${var.ip_list}"
  }
```

it returns the following:

```
$ terraform  apply 

Error: module.openstack.openstack_compute_secgroup_v2.secgroup_1: rule.3.cidr must be a single value, not a list
```

but is there a way to do it right?

Comment: It seems that my trouble will be solved in terraform 0.12 with the dynamic "rule" {} syntax...

Comment: Where is the dynamic `rule` syntax documented? I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have environment to test below command.  The idea should be in right direction.

You should be fine to adjust

```
resource "openstack_compute_secgroup_v2" "secgroup_1" {
  count       = "${length(${var.ip_list})}"
  name        = "a_cluster_${count.index}"
  description = "some security group"

  rule {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    ip_protocol = "tcp"
    cidr        = "${element(var.ip_list, count.index)}"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the question, but "[${var.ip_list}]" still returns an error.

Comment: What's the error message, did you have the double quotes, like this: `"${var.ip_list}"`?

Comment: oups, updated again, don't know how to copy paste anymore.

Comment: "[${var.ip_list}]" return 
```
Error: module.openstack.openstack_compute_secgroup_v2.secgroup_1: 1 error(s) occurred:

* module.openstack.openstack_compute_secgroup_v2.secgroup_1: At column 1, line 1: output of an HIL expression must be a string, or a single list (argument 2 is TypeList) in: [${var.ip_list}]
```

Comment: ic, that part only allow one CIDR, interesting.

Comment: Updated answer, can you check?

Comment: That will give me two security groups with one rule each. I want one group with many rules, I know that I can hard code as many rule as I want, but I want to do it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

If you can upgrade to terraform 0.12 use the dynamic nested block:
with `ip_list = ["11.11.0.0/16","22.22.22.0/8", "33.33.33.33" ...]`

```
 "openstack_compute_secgroup_v2" "secgroup_1" {
  name        = "a_cluster"
  description = "some security group"

 dynamic "rule" {
    for_each = ${var.ip_list}

   content{
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    ip_protocol = "tcp"
    cidr        = rule

  }
  }
}
```